# how to generate an array collection without sorting in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like below,

```
var array=[];
array[0]={id:BBB,Name:"BBB"}
array[1]={id:AAA,Name:"AAA"}
```

and I want to convert this array into an array collection like below

```
var collection={}
array.forEach(function(arr){
  collection[arr.id]=true;
});
Output : collection={AAA:true,BBB:true} // this is output is sorted in alphabetic order, actually what i want is like below,

Output : collection={BBB:true,AAA:true} // this is the expected result
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: @Archer: No, they aren't.

Comment: Objects are unordered, or at least not-ordered-as-you-might-think.

Comment: just keep the array.

Comment: @deceze: You know that's no longer true. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will never stop acting as if it is true, since fundamentally objects aren't about order. :)

Comment: @Archer: Okay: https://jsfiddle.net/La2c09yt/ In Chrome, you'll see that the console displays `o` as `{b: 42, c: 42, a: 42}`, and in any other compliant browser you'll see the JSON is `{"b":42,"c":42,"a":42}`. In both cases, because of the order of object properties.

Comment: @deceze: :-) That's why I always mention that it's there, but not useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've updated it with the test I did myself, which is what I was thinking of when I originally commented, and found myself to be wrong about... https://jsfiddle.net/La2c09yt/1/

Comment: @Archer: You mean the expanded object view, right? Yes, that's what I meant by [my comment elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303768/how-to-generate-an-array-collection-without-sorting-in-javascript/47303853#comment81558540_47303853). I've expanded my answer to address that, it's important information. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No - parsing over the properties.  I honestly thought that returned them sorted, like the expanded object view.  I was just wrong.

Comment: @Archer: Ah! Well, you might have seen them in alpha order in `for-in` once upon a time. Different browsers did `for-in` differently back in the day. The spec doesn't require engines to have `for-in` (or `Object.keys`) follow the order other operations are required to follow (but all modern engines do, now). :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### TL;DR

That's an object, not an "array collection." While object properties have order (which is not alphabetical), it's usually not useful and best to largely ignore that fact. You're probably looking at this in devtools and expanding the display of an object; in that view, devtools will likely show you the properties alphabetically to make it easy for you to find what you're looking for.

#### More detail than necessary

You're adding entries to an object (not an "array collection"). The order of properties in an object is complex (they do have order as of ES2015), but basically for an object's "own" properties that order is the order in which you added them (except things that look like *integer indexes* are handled differently).

However, if you look at an expanded representation of an object in devtools, it may well show you the object's properties alphabetically. That's just a convenience feature for you, it doesn't mean the object's properties are in that order.

For instance:

```js
var o = {};
o.b = 42;
o.c = 42;
o.a = 42;
console.log("object", o);
console.log("json", JSON.stringify(o));
```

```html
Open the browser's devtools, then hit Run.
```

On Chrome, when I run that, I see this:

[image]

Note the order, `b`, `c`, `a` — the order I added the properties.

But if I expand that object with the little arrow:

[image]

In the expanded view, it shows them as `a`, `b`, `c` — alphabetic for convenience.

Also note that the JSON is in object order (this is required by the spec, so while JSON doesn't have order at all, JSON created by serializing a JavaScript object with `JSON.stringify` will, on a compliant JavaScript engine, list the properties in object order).

The order of object properties is not something it's usually useful to use; they're too hard to control. If you want order, use an array. But as it seems you don't want order, that's fine, just don't worry about the order the resulting object's properties appear to be in.

Comment: Plus 1 for you and minus 1 for me for thinking otherwise :(

Comment: I guess the confusion of thinking that the properties are ordered alphabetically is due to when you expand the object in the dev console, it orders the properties for you.

Comment: @George: ***Very*** good point, I'll flag that up in the answer.

Comment: @Archer: You're only wrong in some situations; I'm wrong in others. :-) See George's note above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much I got confused looking at the dev tools.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see this jsfiddle my array object is still sorted in the console.log https://jsfiddle.net/wjrxetbb/1/

Comment: @MuruGan That's the browser doing that.  I've added something extra for you... https://jsfiddle.net/wjrxetbb/2/

Comment: @MuruGan: As Archer said, that's devtools doing that. I address this in the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but the array object is stored in the sorted order in the database not in the actual format

Comment: @MuruGan: How is that relevant?